# How do I export terraform output to a log file using PHP?

Tags: php, terraform

I have created a PHP page where I can read the console output of terraform. But I am having issues exporting these outputs to a log file. I tried using fwrite but I got a blank file. I am using the code below to get the near to real time output of terraform.

```
  if (isset($_POST['button1']))
  {
    $cmd1 = 'C:\terraform\terraform.exe init';
    
    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

    $proc1 = popen("$cmd1 2>&1", 'r');
    echo '<pre>';
    while (!feof($proc1))
    {
      echo fread($proc1, 4096);
      @ flush();
    }
    echo '</pre>';
  }
```

Comment: You could run `terraform.exe output` if by outputs you mean actual terraform `outputs`.

Comment: I mean the console outputs when we run any terraform dommands like Terraform init, Terraform Plan, etc